# Update Data in Data Extension Through API is not working salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm trying to update the record in Data extension through update API request and system is responding with status ok but data is not updated in DE. But data is not updated in MC data extension. What could be wrong with my input request?

> **Input Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>XXXXXXX</Username>
            <Password>XXXXXXX</Password>
         </UsernameToken>       
      </Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <UpdateRequest  xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options>
            </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
             <Client>
                <ID>XXXX</ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <CustomerKey>BICS</CustomerKey>
                  <Properties>
                        <Property>
                              <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                              <Value>sathishkumar.p20@+1gmail.com</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                              <Name>FirstName</Name>
                              <Value>Sathish</Value>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                              <Name>LastName</Name>
                              <Value>kumar</Value>
                        </Property>
                  </Properties>
            </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

> **Output Response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:0eed5468-c301-40e7-accc-5df106b76db7</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:24065352-1375-47cb-a87e-3133bd6283c3</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-82520857-7126-41c9-b8b0-3c2425ecfc48">
            <wsu:Created>2017-05-19T12:18:29Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2017-05-19T12:23:29Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RequestID>c3b12530-da0d-4c62-87df-0605105673ba</RequestID>
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
      </CreateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What SOAP Action are you using in your header for the request envelope?

Comment: @EliotHarper  on header, we dont any action. in Body we are using update request.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose not to define the Action in the Header of your request payload, then you must include the Action in the SOAP envelope. The following request envelope will work.

You will need to make a POST request to the [corresponding endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/working_with_soap_web_service_api.htm) for your instance (e.g. 'POST https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx') and you will **also** need to update the `a:To` element in the envelope below to reflect the correct endpoint.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope
  xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
  xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
    <Security
      xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>XXXXXXX</Username>
        <Password>XXXXXXX</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <UpdateRequest
      xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Client>
          <ID>XXXX</ID>
        </Client>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>BICS</CustomerKey>
        <Properties>
          <Property>
            <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
            <Value>sathishkumar.p20@+1gmail.com</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>FirstName</Name>
            <Value>Sathish</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>LastName</Name>
            <Value>kumar</Value>
          </Property>
      </Properties>
    </Objects>
  </UpdateRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```